# C library for standard input operations with data validation and error check

Tags: c, validation, io

I have implemented a C library to perform basic input operations on built-in data types with various error checks of more complexity. Any improvements or suggestions are appreciated.

[GitHub](https://github.com/venudayyam/SMART-INPUT-LIBRARY)

### smartinput.h

```
/*
 * This library 'smartinput' is written in c programming.
 * by @venudayyam (binary_10)
 *  
 * The library contains subroutines which perform basic input
 * operations on a built-in data types and provide robust
 * error checking.
 * 
 * It is recommend not to mix the stadard input functions with these
 * library functions when performing operations on standard input stream
 * 
 * routines are meant to be used only when input stream is connected to keyboard.
 * routines expect valid arguments to be passed (if any).
 * 
 * 
 * 
 * 
 *  PROS:
 * 
 * - data overflow and underflow check on input
 * 
 * - input buffer is flushed(empty) after each operation.
 * 
 * - input value is said to be valid only when
 *   it can be stored in the specified variable (data type) `as it is`.
 *   otherwise it is invalid.
 * 
 */

#ifndef SMARTINPUT_H

#define SMARTINPUT_H
#include <stdbool.h>


bool get_char(char *ch);
char* get_line(char *_s, int _len);

/* trailing white spaces are preserved */
char* get_string(char *_s, int _len);  

bool get_short(short *value);
bool get_ushort(unsigned short *value);

bool get_int(int *value);
bool get_uint(unsigned int *value);

bool get_long(long *value);
bool get_ulong(unsigned long *value);

bool get_ullong(unsigned long long *value);
bool get_llong(long long *value);

bool get_float(float *value);
bool get_double(double *value);
bool get_ldouble(long double *value);


#endif
```

#### smartinput.c

```
/*
 * This library 'smartinput' is written in c programming.
 * by @venudayyam (binary_10)
 *  
 * The library contains subroutines to perform basic input
 * operations on a built-in data types and provide robust
 * error checking.
 * 
 * It is recommend not to mix the stadard input functions with these
 * library functions when performing operations on standard input stream
 * 
 * routines are meant to be used only when input stream is connected to keyboard.
 * routines expect valid arguments to be passed (if any).
 * 
 * 
 * 
 * 
 *  PROS:
 * 
 * - data overflow and underflow check on input
 * 
 * - input buffer is flushed(empty) after each operation.
 * 
 * - input value is said to be valid only when
 *   it can be stored in the specified variable (data type) `as it is`.
 *   otherwise it is invalid.
 * 
 */


#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include "smartinput.h"

#define BUF_SIZE (1024)
static char buffer[BUF_SIZE];


char* get_line(char *_s, int _len)
{
    int ch;
    size_t i = 0;

    scanf(" ");
    while ((ch=getc(stdin)) != EOF && ch != '\n')
    {
        if (i < _len-1)
            _s[i++] = ch;
    }
    _s[i] = '\0';

    return _s;
}


char* get_string(char *_s, int _len)
{
    int ch;
    size_t i = 0;

    while ((ch=getc(stdin)) != EOF && ch != '\n')
    {
        if (i < _len-1)
            _s[i++] = ch;
    }
    _s[i] = '\0';

    return _s;
}


bool get_char(char *value)
{
    fgets(buffer,3,stdin);
    *value = buffer[0];
    if ((buffer[1] == '\0' && buffer[0] == '\n') ||
        (buffer[2] == '\0' && buffer[1] == '\n'))
    {
         return true;
    }
    else
    {
        if (buffer[0] != '\0')
        {
            scanf("%*[^\n]");
            getchar();
        }
        return false;
    }
}


bool get_short(short *value)
{
    char *temp;
    long v;

    get_line(buffer, BUF_SIZE);
    errno = 0;
    v = strtol(buffer,&temp,10);
    *value = v;
    if (errno == ERANGE || v > SHRT_MAX || v < SHRT_MIN 
                                        || *temp != '\0')
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}


bool get_ushort(unsigned short *value)
{
    char *temp;
    unsigned long v;

    get_line(buffer, BUF_SIZE);
    errno = 0;
    v = strtoul(buffer,&temp,10);
    *value = v;
    if (errno == ERANGE || v > USHRT_MAX || *temp != '\0')
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}


bool get_int(int *value)
{
    char *temp;
    long v;

    get_line(buffer, BUF_SIZE);
    errno = 0;
    v = strtol(buffer,&temp,10);
    *value = v;
    if (errno == ERANGE || v > INT_MAX || v < INT_MIN 
                                       || *temp != '\0')
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}


bool get_uint(unsigned int *value)
{
    char *temp;
    unsigned long v;

    get_line(buffer, BUF_SIZE);
    errno = 0;
    v = strtoul(buffer,&temp,10);
    *value = v;
    if (errno == ERANGE || v > UINT_MAX || *temp != '\0')
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}


bool get_long(long *value)
{
    char *temp;

    get_line(buffer, BUF_SIZE);
    errno = 0;
    *value = strtol(buffer,&temp,10);
    if (errno == ERANGE || *temp != '\0')
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}


bool get_ulong(unsigned long *value)
{
    char *temp;

    get_line(buffer, BUF_SIZE);
    errno = 0;
    *value = strtoul(buffer,&temp,10);
    if (errno == ERANGE || *temp != '\0')
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}


bool get_llong(long long *value)
{
    char *temp;

    get_line(buffer, BUF_SIZE);
    errno = 0;
    *value = strtoll(buffer,&temp,10);
    if (errno == ERANGE || *temp != '\0')
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}


bool get_ullong(unsigned long long *value)
{
    char *temp;

    get_line(buffer, BUF_SIZE);
    errno = 0;
    *value = strtoull(buffer,&temp,10);
    if (errno == ERANGE || *temp != '\0')
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}


bool get_float(float *value)
{
    char *temp;

    get_line(buffer, BUF_SIZE);
    errno = 0;
    *value = strtof(buffer,&temp);
    if (errno == ERANGE || *temp != '\0')
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}

bool get_double(double *value)
{
    char *temp;

    get_line(buffer, BUF_SIZE);
    errno = 0;
    *value = strtod(buffer,&temp);
    if (errno == ERANGE || *temp != '\0')
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}

bool get_ldouble(long double *value)
{
    char *temp;

    get_line(buffer, BUF_SIZE);
    errno = 0;
    *value = strtold(buffer,&temp);
    if (errno == ERANGE || *temp != '\0')
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
```

#### sample.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "smartinput.h"

#define MAX_NAME 256

typedef struct _record
{
    char name[MAX_NAME];
    size_t id;
    char section;
}record;


void get_record(record *r)
{
    printf("name    : ");
    while (!get_line(r->name,MAX_NAME))
        fprintf(stderr,"error: invalid name. try again..\n");

    printf("section : ");
    while (!(get_char(&r->section) && r->section >= 'A'
                                   && r->section <= 'E'))
        fprintf(stderr,"error: invalid section. (select 'A'-'E'). try again..\n");

    printf("id      : ");
    while (!get_ulong(&r->id))
        fprintf(stderr,"error: invalid id. try again..\n");    
}


int main(void)
{
    record r;
    get_record(&r);
    printf("name : %s\nsec  : %c\nid  : %lu",r.name,r.section,r.id);
}
```

.

```
/* sample inputs and outputs of `get_int()` (note. sizeof(int) = 4) */

"2147483647\n"    -- true  (INT_MAX)
"2147483648\n"    -- false 
"-2147483648\n"   -- true  (INT_MIN)
"-2147483649\n"   -- false
"25ds\n"          -- false
"asdjkljasdf\n"   -- false 
"25 256\n"        -- false
"+1\n"            -- true
"-1\n"            -- true
EOF               -- false
" 1\n"            -- true
```

Comment: Good to add sample input, yet since input is _text_,  better to clearly indicate the text entered input including white space and newlines like `"123\n"`, `" 123\n"`, `"123 x\n"`, `"\n123\n"`.

Comment: Please be careful with edits after the question has been answer. See this help page https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers.

Comment: I have only edited description here, the code is left unchanged @pacmaninbw

Comment: Identifiers beginning with an underscore are reserved for the implementation - you'll want to fix some of your parameter names and structure tags.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Overall, a worth goal and a good coding attempt, yet many problems.

1. Questionable functionality in `get_line()` and `get_string()`.  On `EOF`, both return a pointer to the supplied `char` array so the calling code lacks `EOF` distinguishably.  Functions are certainly a problem should a rare input error occur.
2. Questionable functionality in `get_line()` as it can get more that 1 line with `scanf(" ")`.  I'd expect the function to get 1 *line* of input only.

   ```
   char* get_line(char *_s, int _len) {
       ....
       scanf(" ");
   ```
3. Use of `int` for buffer size when `size_t` is the right-size for array sizes.

   ```
   //char* get_line(char *_s, int _len);
   //char* get_string(char *_s, int _len); 
   char* get_line(char *_s, size_t _len);
   char* get_string(char *_s, size_t _len);
   ```
4. Mis-leading comment `/* trailing white spaces are preserved */`.  For both `get_line()` and `char* get_string()`, the *trailing* white spaces (aside from `'\n'`) are preserved.
5. There is no function to get a *line* that includes the potential `'\n'`.  C library defines a *line* as including that.

   > A text stream is an ordered sequence of characters composed into *lines*, each line consisting of zero or more characters plus a terminating new-line character. Whether the last line requires a terminating new-line character is implementation-defined.  C11 7.21.2 1
6. With `smartinput.c`, put `#include "smartinput.h"` first as that will help detect any missing `#include <xxx.h>` that are needed in `smartinput.h`.

   ```
   #include "smartinput.h"
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <string.h>
   ...
   ```
7. Not a fan of using a global `char buffer[]` especially where a short local array would do.
8. Integer conversion problems.  1) return value of `get_line()` is not checked - not that it helps much given the above no EOF detect issue.  Without detecting EOF, conversion may use the previous contents of global `buffer`,  2) "No conversion" is not detected.  3) On conversion outside `short` range, `errno` is not set. and the value is set to the end of the `short` range.  Similar troubles with all integer conversion functions.  [Alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29378380/2410359)
9. The get FP routines also fail to detect no conversion.  Those FP routines have a special implementation defined (ID) behavior concerning *underflow* not handled by OP's code.  Noted as follows:

   > If the result underflows (7.12.1), the functions return a value whose magnitude is no greater than the smallest normalized positive number in the return type; whether `errno` acquires the value `ERANGE` is implementation-defined. §7.22.1.3 10
10. Questionable test code.  As `get_line(s,...)` always return `s`, the following will only print if `r->name == NULL`

    ```
    while (!get_line(r->name,MAX_NAME))   
      fprintf(stderr,"error: invalid name. try again..\n");
    ```
11. Design asymmetry.  The get line/string return the value on the others return a `bool` flag indicating success.  I'd expect all to return `bool`.

---

12. Minor: `()` not needed with `#define BUF_SIZE (1024)`
13. Pedantic: `char* get_line(char *_s, int _len)` writes before `_s` if `_len <= 0`.  Better to detect and return that perform UB.  If code did call `get_line(char *_s, 0)`, then `if (i < _len-1)` would become `f (i < SIZE_MAX)` allowing buffer overruns.

Alternative `get_line()`, something like:

```
char *get_line(char * s, size_t n) {
  if (n == 0) {
    return NULL; // or TBD on how to handle pathological case.
  }
  n--;

  int ch;
  size_t i = 0;
  while (i < n && (ch = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF) {
    s[i++] = (char) ch;
    if (ch == '\n') break;
  }
  s[i] = '\0';

  // Consume rest of line
  while (ch != '\n' && ch != EOF) {
    ch = fgetc(stdin);
  }

  if (ch == EOF) {
    if (i == 0 || ferror(stdin)) {
      return NULL;
    }
  }
  return s;
}
```

Comment: I have traded **no conversion** with the value of temp (endptr). my implementation is such that `*temp` will never be equal to `'\0'` if no conversion occurs (considering get_line() is unchanged)

Comment: `scanf(" ");` _A sequence of white-space characters (space, tab, newline, etc.; see isspace(3)).  This directive matches any amount of white space, including none, in the input_. The rest of characters until `'\n'` are read by `get_line()`.

Comment: now i understand that by the term **line** you meant _"line consisting of zero or more characters plus a terminating new-line character"_ so that "\n25x\n" is not a single line anymore. Yeah, i should probably rename `get_line()` to `get_input()`, take care of possible `EOF` input and make it `static`. Implement a new version of `get_line()` function.

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't restrict your library routines only to work with the `stdin` stream specifically.

It would be way more useful and flexibly applicable, if you introduce another parameter of type `FILE*` for all of your functions:

```
bool fget_char(FILE* stream, char *ch);
char* fget_line(FILE* stream, char *_s, int _len);

/* trailing white spaces are preserved */
char* fget_string(FILE* stream, char *_s, int _len);  

bool fget_short(FILE* stream, short *value);
bool fget_ushort(FILE* stream, unsigned short *value);
// ...
```

and provide convenience implementations for

```
bool get_char(char *ch) {
    return fget_char(stdin,ch);
}
char* get_line(char *_s, int _len) {
    return fget_line(stdin,_s,_len);
}

/* trailing white spaces are preserved */
char* get_string(char *_s, int _len) {
    return fget_string(stdin,_s,_len);
}

bool get_short(short *value) {
    return fget_short(stdin,value);
}
bool get_ushort(unsigned short *value) {
    return fget_ushort(stdin,value);
}
// ...
```

which just call the corresponding `fget_xxx()` functions passing `stdin` there.